# Finder takes forever to open a directory with a lot of subfolders on NTFS or NAS

Tags: finder, filesystem, folders, nas, ntfs

On my external NTFS HDD I have my music collection with over 3800 artists in it, which is structured like this: `/Music/Artist/Year - Album/`, each artist as a separate sub-folder. When I try to open the `Music` directory in Finder it takes from 10 to 35 seconds to show me the list of sub-directories there. Something similar to this happens when I access such directory on a EXT4-formatted HDD in a QNAP NAS over the network (SMB or AFP).

Any Windows machine opens and displays the same folder in Explorer near-instantly both locally and over the network.

What causes this behavior on MacOS and how do I make MacOS list the subfolders quicker, like on Windows?

P.S. I use MacOS 10.13 on a 2017 MBP. The view mode in Finder is list view, size calculation is ticked off. For NTFS I tried using both in-built MacOS driver and the Paragon one.

Comment: It's fast locally on HFS+ and on the NAS I use (just tested), so I suspect it's primarily a result of using NTFS or a slow NAS/network. But the cause and possible is most likely different for NTFS and NAS, so can you please focus your question on one or the other? It might also help to add some details about the view you are using in Finder, the NTFS driver in question and other details.

Comment: Updated the question a bit. So, for NTFS driver I tried both in-built MacOS 10.13 driver and the one that comes with `Paragon NTFS for Mac 15`. We can eliminate the NAS/network as a bottleneck because the same SMB share loads in 2 seconds on Windows. Am I correct? I surely saw someone on youtube complaining about similar problem with NAS shares (https://youtu.be/BEwEN9Vc1pQ), but I am not sure the NAS part of the equation is really relevant here, or is it?

Comment: How are you mounting the QNAP share of the same folder? SMB 2 or 3? (There is a checkbox in QNAP control panel) I have seen similar things happen with rsync where there are files are directories with special characters in them like apostrophes or even spaces. I suspect there is an issue with how QNAP shares SMB but the jury is still out on that.

Comment: I use smb 3. Moreover, I tried hooking up my external HDD to a Windows 10 machine, making the directory in question a shared folder and accessing it via SMB from Finder. It takes the same 20 to 30 seconds of blank Finder window before the subfolders load up. That means we can exclude QNAP as a bottleneck, correct?